# Webpage not loading on WKWebView

Tags: swiftui, wkwebview

Im trying to load a specific webpage with the below code. Page loads on the browser on my mac and iphone, Also it works on `SFSafariViewController` in my app. But `WKWebView` only shows a white screen. `WKWebView` can load any other page like google.com, youtube.com etc. How do i troubleshoot this? I do not get any errors either. I need to figure out why I'm only having an issue with this particular web page. Any help would be much appropriated!

```
@State private var isLoading = true
@State private var error: Error? = nil
let url: URL?

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if let error = error {
            Text(error.localizedDescription)
                .foregroundColor(.pink)
        } else if let url = url {
            WebView(url: url,
                    isLoading: $isLoading,
                    error: $error)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            if isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            }
        } else {
            Text("Sorry, we could not load this url.")
        }
        
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    @Binding var isLoading: Bool
    @Binding var error: Error?
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        let wkwebView = WKWebView()
        wkwebView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        wkwebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        return wkwebView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: WebView
        init(_ parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            parent.isLoading = true
        }
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            print("loading didFinish")
            parent.isLoading = false
        }
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
            print("loading error: \(error)")
            parent.isLoading = false
            parent.error = error
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: So what does the error print out?

Comment: As I have mentioned. There are no errors

Answer (score 0):

I use to have this issue. For me WebView worked as it should except when I placed the WebView inside a `.sheet()`.

What I did to fix the issue was make the url in WebView `@Binding`.

I'm not sure why it gives a blank white page. My guess is that it preloads the webpage but since the URL is empty, it loads nothing.